# Extend a result holding in one dimension to multiple dimensions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was seeing some experimental results and I was wondering if it was possible to prove them mathematically.

The problem boils down to this -

$$
a_1 > a_2 \\
c_2 > c_1 \\
d_1 < d_2
$$
All values are positive constants.

We are given Condition A that

$$
\frac{a_1}{d_1} + \frac{c_1}{d_2} = \frac{a_2}{d_1} + \frac{c_2}{d_2}
$$

I need to find an $e$ such that

$$
\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{d_1^2 + e^2}} + \frac{c_1}{\sqrt{d_2^2 + e^2}} < \frac{a_2}{\sqrt{d_1^2 + e^2}} + \frac{c_2}{\sqrt{d_2^2 + e^2}}
$$

Essentially, Condition A is a result of dividing constants $a_1$ by distance $d_1$, $c_1$ by distance $d_2$ etc.

I want to find an $e$ for 2 dimensions (instead of a line, we use the XY plane), as you can see, $\sqrt{d_1^2 + e^2}$ is the Euclidean distance of a point.

I am extremely new to the forum and higher maths in general, so I am looking for pointers on where to get started. I tried basic arithmetic manipulations but I am not sure of where to start.

Thank you!